# Parent categories

Tags: categories, revit-api, autodesk

I am wondering about the following:

There is a category called **Mass Walls**, this category has a ParentCategory: **Mass**
The category Mass has SubCategories. But in that list you don't see: Mass Walls

What kind of Categories is: **Mass Walls**

because it looks like this:

ParentCategory

- ChildCategory

---

- SubCategorie1
- SubCategorie2
- SubCategorie3
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be for a GraphicsStyle of the same name and is probably for some internal usage instead of allowing elements to use it.